# nhibernate.search / lucene.net multi-lingual analyser

Tags: c#, lucene.net, multilingual, nhibernate.search

I am trying to integrate NHibernate.Search into a multi-lingual website.  Now, this website contains a class `Article` which is multilingual.  This is done by having a seperate class - `Article_CultureInfo` which stores the language-specific content.  Fields of `Article` are

```
Article
-------
ID
Name
```

And `Article_CultureInfo` are:

```
Article_CultureInfo
-------
ID
ArticleId
CultureCode
PageTitle
Content
```

I am using `Nhibernate.Search.Mapping` to map out the field/document information.  I would like to incorporate search features like stemming and synonym analysis where possible based on the language.  Is there any way the Lucene Analyser can be specified at run-time, not compile time / initialisation?

Say we are analysing the content of `PageTitle` which is to be stored in the respective Lucene index - This content can be English, French, Italian, etc based on the value of `CultureCode`.  Thus, the analyser should change based on this value.  I have tried implementing a custom `MultilingualAnalyser`, however the only data available to me are the string to be analysed, i.e the value of `PageTitle`.  From that only, I cannot deduce the language.  (I could look into language detection techniques but that is out of the scope since I already know specifically what it is, and would be overkill and not 100% reliable.)

If I were to have apart from the tokens, an instance of the object, I could be able to get the `CultureCode` value out of it, and analyse accordingly.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - I really wish to avoid using Lucene.Net directly since NHibernate.Search looks to integrate very nicely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've basically done a work-around for this method - Quite an overkill but works.

I've created a new implementation of `IGetter`, which is used for multilingual properties, which I called `MultilingualGetter`.  This is basically the same as the `BasicGetter` - I couldn't extend from it as for some reason it is `sealed`, so I copied the code.

What this `IGetter` does is: When the `Get()` method is called on it, it is given the `target` object.  This is the instance of the class that contains the property.  I check that it implements an interface for multilingual objects which I've created, `IMultilingualContentInfo`.  It then retrieves the current culture from the `IMultilingualContentInfo`, and appends it on the front of the actual text, e.g [en]Hello World!.

This text is then passed on to a custom analyzer I created which parses the culture as well, and can deduce what it is.  It is then using a `SnowballFilter` to stem the text based on the language.

Below is the code for `Get()` method of the custom `IGetter` implementation - `IMultilingualContentInfo`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of the Property from the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The object to get the Property value from.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The value of the Property for the target.
    /// </returns>
    public object Get(object target)
    {

        if (target is IMultilingualContentInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                IMultilingualContentInfo multiLingualTarget = (IMultilingualContentInfo)target;
                string s = (string)property.GetValue(target, new object[0]);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                {
                    MultilingualLuceneTextContent mlText = new MultilingualLuceneTextContent();
                    mlText.Culture = multiLingualTarget.CultureInfo.GetCultureCode();
                    s = mlText.GetTextIncCulture();

                }
                return s;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new PropertyAccessException(e, "Exception occurred", false, clazz, propertyName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Multilingual Getter is only available on IMultilingualContentInfo objects");
        }

    }
```